# can we remove the enter working as submit in comments?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comment, user-interface

Aan we change the working of the enter key when busy writing a comment

At the moment it works like clicking the "add comment" button, and I rather would not like that functionality.

Comment: This is an old peeve for many of us. See for example [this thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/779/11619) for an early discussion. The SE team is unlikely to change it back after all these years in spite of some of use not liking this behavior. That thread is tagged *status-by-design* meaning that they want it to behave like this.

Comment: More discussion and links to similar content on Meta.SE can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309/allow-newline-in-comments).

Comment: Just to note: if you want to skip a line while typing, you can use Shift+Enter.

Comment: can we not exchange that functionality that enter becomes a new line and shift enter becomes an "add comments"

Comment: @Willemien The Shift-Enter skips a line while one is typing a comment. 
When the comment is posted, the new line will be removed; it will not be visible. 

No, we cannot change the functionality. We don't control the SE software.